# Redirect requests for external IP's to a local IP

Tags: networking, redirect, ip, host, ipv4

I am working on a project form my company. We have an application that we unfortunately lost the source code for, it has the IP address of our external server hard-coded into it. We have recently changed servers, and need to change where the application tries to access our database. I'd really prefer not to reinvent the wheel, and remake the application...

I tried using the route command, but no dice.

```
route -p [new server] mask 255.255.255.255 [old server] metric 50 if [interface]
```

I set up a temp webserver on port 80 of the new box, typed in the old IP address in a browser of a machine with the said route added to it's tables, and it still went to the old server.

Any help making the route command work, or plausible alternatives? Eg: software to redirect, router tricks...etc.

- Note: We tried using a reverse name lookup on our private dns server, but that failed as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the IP address is hardcoded in the binary, you can probably grep for it. It's probably represented as four bytes. You can then replace it with the new IP address using a hex editor.

Comment: Again, the application is compressed.

Comment: If it's a commonly used compression method it can probably be undone.

Comment: It was NSPack. We decompressed it and grepped. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an iptables firewall somewhere on the route you can use DNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d [old server] -j DNAT --to-destination [new server]
```

It doesn't matter where exactly you run this, so long as it sees packets addressed to `[old server]` and has a valid route to `[new server]`, so that could be on the host running the application, any intermediate router, or your edge firewall.

Of course you could always just edit the address inside the binary itself....

Comment: We don't have a linux box firewall yet, though it's in the making. Thanks for the instruction.

Comment: The binary editing option was only half-joking - it shouldn't be too hard to do given the old address is known for searching. The other option would be to make your [new server] claim to have both the new address and the old address and then your route command would work as expected. You can add multiple addresses in the "Advanced TCP/IP settings" dialogue for the network interface.

Comment: It's a compressed binary. I would have done that if I could have =/

Answer (score 0):

In your firewall/router set up NAT for that public IP so that it routes to your new private ip.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a route to the new sever like you mentioned, because at the first router hop the packet will be routed to the old server.

You might be able to point the route at the local host, add the old server as an IP address on a local interface, and write a proxy server to forward the requests to the old server.

The best option IMO is to figure out how to decompress the binary and hex edit it. Do you know what language it's written in? Or call your lawyer to get the source code back. =)

Answer (score -1):

Use the hosts file to route all requests to external IP to a local IP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: The hosts file will only be effective if it's doing a DNS lookup. If that's the case I think fixing the DNS entry might be simpler and more maintainable in the long run.

Comment: It's an IP, not a domain name. if it referenced our company's domain name, we'd not be having this problem